# Editing data in multiple columns from front-end

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in the database, I can edit a column of particular row at a time. but, i want to edit multiple columns of a single row at a time with an option of edit and then save it to the database ,we can do it from back-end by editing in the database itself. But, i want to do it from front-end .Now i am able to display the data in the table. I am new to coding , so can anyone help me where to start for this particular task of editing multiple columns at the same time.
Here is the code for displaying the data..

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include 'header.php';
include 'gobacktomenu.php';
$TND_ID =  $_GET['TND_ID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM new_tnds WHERE TND_ID = ('".$TND_ID."')"; 
$result = $link->query($sql);
echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'><table border = '1'><font size = '2' face='verdana'>
<th>TND ID</th><th>Site name S1</th><th>Site name S2</th><th>Call sign S1</th><th>Idea ID S1</th><th>Call sign S2</th><th>Idea ID S2</th><th>Site to integrate</th><th>True azimuth (°) S1</th><th>True azimuth (°) S2</th><th>Pathlength (km)</th><th>TR Antenna diameter (m)</th><th>TR Antenna height (m) S1</th><th>TR Antenna height (m) S2</th><th>Channel ID S1</th><th>Channel ID S2</th><th>Design frequency S1</th><th>Design frequency S2</th><th>Polarization</th><th>Radio model</th><th>TX power (dBm)</th><th>Receive signal (dBm)</th><th>Planning Remarks</th><th>Projects Remarks Uploaded by</th><th>O & M Remarks Uploaded by</th><th>Planning Remarks Uploaded by</th><th>TXN NOC Remarks Uploaded by</th></tr>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        echo "<tr><td>".$row["TND_ID"]."</td><td>".$row["Site_name_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["Site_name_S2"]."</td><td>".$row["Call_sign_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["Idea_ID_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["Call_sign_S2"]."</td><td>".$row["Idea_ID_S2"]."</td><td>".$row["Site_to_integrate"]."</td><td>".$row["True_azimuth_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["True_azimuth_S2"]."</td><td>".$row["Path_length_(km)"]."</td><td>".$row["TR_Antenna_diameter_(m)_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["TR_Antenna_height_(m)_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["TR_Antenna_height_(m)_S2"]."</td><td>".$row["#1_Channel_ID_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["#1_Channel_ID_S2"]."</td><td>".$row["#1_Design_frequency_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["#1_Design_frequency_S2"]."</td><td>".$row["Polarization"]."</td><td>".$row["Radio_model_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["TX_power_(dBm)_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["Receive_signal_(dBm)_S1"]."</td><td>".$row["Planning_Remarks"]."</td><td>".$row["Projects_remarksupdated_user_name"]."</td><td>".$row["O_M_remarksupdated_user_name"]."</td><td>".$row["Planning_remarksupdated_user_name"]."</td><td>".$row["txn_noc_remarksupdated_user_name"]."</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table></div>";
$link->close();
?>
```

Comment: you will edit it with html and php?

Comment: i don't know which language to use for editing data from front end. can u please suggest how to proceed. thanks

Comment: i use html and some javascript for front end, do you want to edit all columns where the key matches one of your keys in your primary column or do you want to edit all the values in a row of a single column . ?

Comment: I want to edit multiple columns of a single row.thanks

Comment: you need to create a while loop for each column and fetch the information. if you can do that i can show you the structure and what to put where

Answer (score 0):

you can use this structure ,this can be used for editing 2 tables and multiple columns table a has columns (aid,a1,a2) table b has columns (bid,b1,b2) i know code looks little rough but just wrote it in 5 min to give you an idea

```
<?php
//this only executes when button is clicked
if (isset($_POST["submit"] && $_POST["submit"]!=""){
    $counta=$_POST["aid"];
    //loops through the posts inside here do your query with the set command
    //like "update a set a1='$a1',a2='$a2" where aid ='$_POST["aid'][$i]"

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $a1[$i]=$_POST["a1"][$i];
        $a2[$i]=$_POST["a2"][$i];
        //your query here
        }
    $countb=$_POST["bid"];
    //loops through the posts inside here do your query with the set command
    //like "update b set b1='$b1',b2='$b2" where aid ='$_POST["bid'][$i]"
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $a1[$i]=$_POST["a1"][$i];
        $a2[$i]=$_POST["a2"][$i];
        }
//now the part before the button gets clicked
//do your query to select data from database
?>

<html>
<body>
//creating loop inside html

<?php
$a=0;
while($rowa = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulta){
?>

//getting the input data
<input type="checkbox" name="aid[]" value="<?php echo $row["aid"]; ?>>
<label>a1</label>
<input type="text" name="a1[]" value="<?php echo $row["a1"]; ?>>
<label>a2</label>
<input type="text" name="a2[]" value="<?php echo $row["a2"]; ?>>
//ending the loop

<?php
$a++;
}
//b works the same as a
$b=0;
while($rowb = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultb){
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="bid[]" value="<?php echo $row["bid"]; ?>>
<label>b1</label>
<input type="text" name="b1[]" value="<?php echo $row["b1"]; ?>>
<label>b2</label>
<input type="text" name="b2[]" value="<?php echo $row["b2"]; ?>>

<?php
$b++;
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use form instead of table while editing and pass the fetched values on input of form and write update query on form submit.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$query = "update details set Site_name_S1='$_POST['submit']',Site_name_S2='$_POST['Site_name_S2']',Call_sign_S1='$_POST['Call_sign_S1']',Idea_ID_S1='$_POST['Idea_ID_S1'] where TND_ID=$_POST['TND_ID']";

$res = mysql_query($query);
}
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['TND_ID'] ;?>" >
<input type="text" name="Site_name_S1" value="<?php echo $row['Site_name_S1'] ;?>" >
<input type="text" name="Site_name_S2" value="<?php echo $row['Site_name_S2'] ;?>" >
<input type="text" name="Call_sign_S1" value="<?php echo $row['Call_sign_S1'] ;?>" >
<input type="text" name="Idea_ID_S1" value="<?php echo $row['Idea_ID_S1'] ;?>" >
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Just check the quotes while writing update query.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the above code is used for submitting the edited data. But how should i be able to display the table with already existing data to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax
Just a fragment of code:
.............

```
     <td><input type="text" row_id=".$some_row_num_from_table." 
col-name=".$some_col_name_from_table." disabled class="some-val" value=".$some_from_base."></td>
```

.............

than little Ajax

```
$('.some-val').dblclick(function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', false);
});

$('.some-val').blur(function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  var send_data = { 'row_id':$(this).attr('row_id'),
                    'col-name':$(this).attr('col-name'),
                    'myval':$(this).val()
                   };
   $.ajax({
     url:'your_url.php',
     data:send_data,
     method: 'post',
     success: function(data){...}
  });
});


your_url.php

if(isset($_POST['row_id'])){
  $sql = "UPDATE mytablename SET `".$_POST['col-name']."` = ".$_POST['myval']." WHERE `row_id` = ".$_POST['row_id'];
$link->query($sql); // it s bad query without protect of sql injection JUST DEMO
}
```